# function is not define and $ not defined in laravel 7

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel-7

I have a fresh created laravel project having downloaded jquery.min.js file from `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js` to the path `public/js/jquery.min.js`. Added the following piece of code to `views/layouts/app.blade.php` :

```
@section('js')
<script type="text/javascript">
    function parameterFormLoad(){
        console.log("test script");
    }
</script>
@endsection
```

When calling `parameterFormLoad()` as follows:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-custom" id="open-parameter-form" onclick="parameterFormLoad()">
 Create
</button>
```

It gives the `ReferenceError` message on function `parameterFormLoad()`. And when I remove `@section('js')` and `@endsection` it gives `ReferenceError` that `$ not found`.

Any help would be highly appreciated.!!!

Comment: What is the full error message without removing the section tags?

Comment: Please include all relevant code and make sure you have correctly loaded jquery script before executing any other scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it by adding `bootstrap.min.js`, `jquery.min.js` scripts in the `<head>` tag.

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
```

and removed `@section('script')` and  `@endsection` from the blade file.

NOTE: make sure that the script tag doesn't set `defer` attribute if `jquery.min.css` and `bootstrap.min.css` are downloaded to project directory.